# NetSuite: FreeMarker List Getting Pushed Down

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I can't figure out why this list is getting pushed down? The list items start at the 4th row. I was hoping the <#compress> directive would truncate any white space but had no affect on the output.

---

blank line/white space 
blank line/white space
blank line/white space
blank line/white space

Ice Cream $50.00
Vanilla

---

--next page--

Ice Cream $50.00
Chocolate

```
<hr
    style="width: 100%; color: #d3d3d3; background-color: #d3d3d3; height: 1px;" />
<!-- start items -->
<#list record.item as item>
<table style="margin-top: 10px; width: 100%;">
<#if item.custcol_comments?contains("cream")>
  <#compress>
  <tr>
        <td colspan="12" style="text-align: center;"><span
            style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 10%; color: #333333;">${item.item}</span><br />${item.description}</td>
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">${item.amount}</td>
</tr>
 </#compress>
  </#if>
</table>
</#list>
<!-- end items -->
<hr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to swap the order of the `table` and `<#list>` tags. What you are doing right now is creating a separate table for every line item, irrespective of whether or not it matches the condition.

```
<table style="margin-top: 10px; width: 100%;">
  <#list record.item as item>
    <#if item.custcol_comments?contains("cream")>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="12" style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-weight: bold; line-height: 10%; color: #333333;">${item.item}</span><br />${item.description}</td>
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">${item.amount}</td>
      </tr>
    </#if>
  </table>
</#list>
```

`<#compress>` will remove whitespace but not empty tables, but in any case the BFO renderer will automatically remove extra whitespace so it's not typically needed in NetSuite templates.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you! I really appreciate your thorough response.